# how to get multiple variable data from repository pattern in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

I am using the laravel repository pattern, here the problem is, I could not get data from the controller. Following below I write some code related to my problem.

```
public function index(){ $data['all_product'] = Product::select('product_name','id','rating_status','thumbnail','hover_img','type','brand_name','sale_price','regular_price')->latest()->get();   


 $data['allDataRv'] = Product::latest()->get();


    $data['deal_product'] = Product::where('deals_day',1)->latest()->get();


    $data['top_selling'] = Product::select('product_name','thumbnail','id','sale_price','regular_price')->where('top_selling',1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->take(4)->get();;



    $data['trending_product'] = Product::select('product_name','thumbnail','id','sale_price','regular_price')->where('trending_product',1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->take(4)->get();



    $data['recent_product'] = Product::select('product_name','thumbnail','id','sale_price','regular_price')->where('Recently_added',1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->take(4)->get();



    $data['top_rateded'] = Product::select('product_name','thumbnail','id','sale_price','regular_price')-\>where('top_rateded',1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->take(4)->get();
    return $data;
}
```

`My Controller:`

```
 public function index(){   
 $data['all_product'] = $this->data->index();




    return view('frontend.index',compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... "I could not get data from the controller" what does that mean?

Comment: what is the error message? try to check if the repository has been successfully called.

Comment: do you declare it in your route? it look likes ```Route::get('/products', [ProductController::class, 'index']);```

Comment: What does `$this->data` in your controller refer to? Do you add something in the controller's constructor?